# Flex/AS3 Change a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, apache-flex

I have this code. I need change variable DiagnosIsWritten=true, when input_diagnos (TextInput) is written something. Can you help me to say all ways, how i can do it.

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        public var DiagnosIsWritten:Boolean;
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGrid id="examsDG" >
      <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn  editable="true" headerText=" width="156" 
  itemRenderer="modules.PatientCardModule.moduls.ToothModule.renderers.examsDG_BiteRenderer"/>
    </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>


examsDG_BiteRenderer.mxml : 
<s:TextInput id="input_diagnos" text="test" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a change listener:

either inline:

```
<s:TextInput id="input_diagnos" text="test" width="100%" height="100%" change="onChange(event)" />
```

or in as3:

```
input_diagnos.addEventListener(spark.events.TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, onChange);

protected function onChange(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
    DiagnosIsWritten = true;
}
```